# Give the more than one parameters in http request angularjs

Tags: angularjs, laravel

My Laravel route is :

```
Route::get('/get_event_history/{data}/{date}', 'HomeController@GetEvents')->name('get_event_history');
```

and I wanted to pass two routes. I am doing like this:

```
$scope.HistoryEventClick=function(imei,date){
   
    var Indata = {'data': imei, 'date': date };

    $http.get('/get_event_history/',params: Indata).success(function (data, status, headers, config){
     
             console.log("Event Data from the query",data.data);
     
    }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        //alert(status)
    });

}
```

Its not working and gives error route not found

Answer (score 0):

You may need to change to this:

```js
$http.get(`/get_event_history/${imei}/${date}`).......
```

Comment: It not working. It give me exception  exception: "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException"

Comment: I have solved it the problem is with the date and time format it is reconizes it as a route

Answer (score 0):

```
$http.get('/get_event_history/'+$routeParams.imei +'/date/'+ $routeParams.date)
```

Comment: So server side route should be like /providerlist/:imei /date/:date